# Spring boot : Repository interface not found with annotations

Tags: java, spring, repository

I created a simple application which save a message in a postgresql database using Spring boot and JPA/Hibernate.
All packages Controller/Service/Repository are in a subpackages.

But I get an error : spring boot doesn't recognize the repository interface in package DAO.

I had another project where all work without using @EnableJpaRepositories but in this project (same structure) I had this problem.

Project structure :

app.shellx (function main())

---- app.shellx.dao

---- app.shellx.controller

---- app.shellx.service

MessageRepository.java

```
package app.shellx.dao;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import app.shellx.model.Message;

@Repository
public interface MessageRepository extends CrudRepository<Message, Long> {

}
```

MessageServiceImpl.java

```
package app.shellx.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import app.shellx.dao.MessageRepository;
import app.shellx.model.Message;

@Service
public class MessageServiceImpl implements MessageService {

    @Autowired
    private MessageRepository messageRepository;

    public void add(Message message) {
        this.messageRepository.save(message);
    }

}
```

Error code in Eclipse :

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Field messageRepository in app.shellx.service.MessageServiceImpl required a bean of type 'app.shellx.dao.MessageRepository' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'app.shellx.dao.MessageRepository' in your configuration.

EDIT : PROBLEM SOLVED.
It was a dependency error.
Just add this maven dependency and it works :

> org.springframework.boot
>      spring-boot-starter-data-jpa
>      2.1.4.RELEASE

Comment: Looks like a component scan issue. Is your class annotated `@SpringBootApplication` in the project root? Where is the import line for the `@Repository` annotation at the MessageRepository class?

Comment: @AlonGadot Yes, only SpringBootApplication in the main package "app.shellx" because componentScan annotation and EnableAutoConfiguration are used by default by Spring Boot. And I don't want to use EnableJpaRepositories because I need to define myself EntityManagerFactory and in my another project I don't use it and it works.

Comment: I don't see the import for the `@Repository` annotation at your MessageRepository class, are you sure you've imported the right one?

Comment: @AlonGadot Yes I did. I just deleted these lines because I thought it was not interesting to show. I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

Name and place the packages correctly,
`com.app` - SpringBootApplication
`com.app.controller` - Controller class
`com.app.repo` - Repo class exdends CrudRepository (If mention any annotation pls remove)
`com.app.model` - Your table class(Entity)

Spring boot will auto configure